# mTLS with OpenID Connect and validating self-signed certificates

Tags: tls, certificates, openid-connect

OIDC says mTLS can be used to authenticate the client. But I haven't read anywhere whether the OIDC Provider is supposed to accept self-signed SSL certificates. Are there any dangers to accepting self-signed certificates? Should these self-signed certificates be rejected when validating the certificate, or are they as secure as CA certificates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to authenticate somebody one need to very the information provided against some expectation on has. With passwords this is the locally stored password hash. With client certificates the expectation is usually that it has been issued by a specific  CA, which one trusts to verify the clients information before issuing the certificate.

A self-signed certificate does not provide such a trust anchor by itself. Therefore it cannot be used for proper authentication, unless the ID provider expects exactly this certificate for the user. For example there could be some enrollment process where the user authenticates itself by some other means and then uploads its self-signed certificate for later authentication and thus associates the certificate with the account.